# using tsoa and swagger-ui, how to generate static path url segments

Tags: node.js, typescript, swagger-ui, openapi, tsoa

I am using tsoa and swagger-ui in a node-ts application and it's generating the swagger doc accordingly.  Instead of generating paths relative to the root ie: `http://localhost:3000/pets` I want to include some static path in front of the controller route like this: `http://api/v1/pets`.  I cannot seem to find how do this in the documentation.  Any tips or tricks that can help point me in the right direction would be appreciated.

EDIT: It looks like this can be set by passing `--baseDir = /api/v1` to tsoa, but I actually want a `/public` and `/secured` url segment, which is what the challenge is.

Thanks in advance,
MG